# How do I send a request to a UDP tracker?

Tags: c#, bittorrent

I am learning about BitTorrent protocol and I managed to make a simple little program that can load a torrent file, parse it, get a tracker from it, then send a GET request to the tracker, and do a handshake with one peer. But now I came by a UDP tracker in the form `udp://example.to:999/announce`.

With a regular tracker I would do (in C#):

```
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(request_string);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

How do I send a request and get a response with an UDP tracker?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the UDP Tracker Protocol that is specified in:
[BEP15 - UDP Tracker Protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20170101194115/http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html).

Comment: Not sure why you would link to an outdated internet archive version. The current version is at http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html and also contains IPv6 support.

Answer (score 0):

The class I needed in C# was `System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient`. If your udp tracker address is `udp://example.to:999/announce`, then you need to initialize your UdpClient with:

```
UdpClient udpTracker = new UdpClient("example.to", 999);
```

Then use appropriate methods for sending and receiving information. For what needs to be sent to the tracker refer to [UDP Tracker Protocol.](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html)